# Fetching all participants of a Telegram channel

Tags: telegram, php-telegram-bot, telegram-api

Using the [Madelineproto PHP library](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto) how can one fetch the list of all participants.

Here is a code snippet that fetches the list of recent participants.

```php
$participantsInfo = $telegramClient->channels->getParticipants([
  'channel' => 'channel#1246538196',
  'filter' => ['_' => 'channelParticipantsContacts'],
  'offset' => 0,
  'limit' => 100
]);
```

The list of supported filters is [here](https://core.telegram.org/type/ChannelParticipantsFilter). However, I cannot see a filter that would allow fetching all participant's info.

Of course, an alternate tedious way would be to run the code snippet periodically and curate the list of participants.

Answer (score -3):

'channel' => '-1246538196',

Comment: what exactly do you not understand?   'channel' => 'channel#1246538196'    replace   'channel' => '-1246538196',